# Hibernate 4 - Call stored procedure having IN as well as OUT parameters

Tags: java, hibernate-4.x, java-stored-procedures

I researched much about how to call stored procedure using hibernate 4 session object with In & OUT params, but no use.

Finally got a clue related to the "SessionImpl". Using this object we can get the Connection object.

Using this connection object can call the prepareCall() method, which will support the IN/OUT params of the procedure.

Following is a sample snippet.

```
        Map<String, String> returnMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Connection connObj = ((SessionImpl)session).connection();
        CallableStatement connStmt = connObj.prepareCall("{ call SCHEMA.PKG_NAME.SP_NAME(?,?,?) }");
        connStmt.setLong(1, 123456);

        connStmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        connStmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        connStmt.execute();

        if(connStmt != null && connStmt.getString(2).equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            returnMap.put("returnID", ExceptionConstants.SUCCESS_STATUS);
            returnMap.put("returnMessage", connStmt.getString(3));  
        } else {
            returnMap.put("returnID", ExceptionConstants.FAILED_STATUS);
            returnMap.put("returnMessage", connStmt.getString(3));
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to call a procedure through Hibernate (version 4.x) session. I had found above mentioned solution. Please share if you have any other solution to achieve proc call ?

Comment: call procedure might be done with native sql createSqlQuery. but this post is only one solution I found with out parameter.